# Smart-Web-App-Banner banner doesn't showing in safari browser

Tags: jquery

when I open my website in android mobile's chrome browser smart banner getting showed.
but same iOS Safari browser doesn't show banner.

I am using this script

```
https://github.com/KZeni/Smart-Web-App-Banner/blob/master/examples/Getting%20Started.md
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually the creator of this script.

I've tested this on a live site that's still using this, today, and it's working perfectly fine with Safari on iOS (https://www.bhc.edu is the site I checked.) It's then just calling the JS & CSS normally via CDNJS and has a pretty-standard:

```
    // Initiate Smart Web Banner
    $().smartWebBanner({
        title: 'BHC',
        author: 'Black Hawk College',
        url: '/'
    });
```

when it's being called on `$(document).ready()`.

So I'm thinking there is something unique going on with your particular setup that's causing things to not work properly or something to that effect. As such, I need some more information so I'm not just left guessing.

Could you provide the URL of the page this is this happening on?

Do take into account that you closing the banner or choosing to save the web app stores a cookie so that it doesn't continually nag the visitor. Is this the case here (I can't say since it'd be cookies within your own browser having been set)?

https://kurtzenisek.com/p/smart-web-banner/ has "Example (with full options)" detailing how you can set `debug` to `true` in the options when calling the script. This can help debug things. If it shows when this is set to true, then I'd definitely consider it's cookies making it not re-show (the duration of these cookies can be configured via these options, as well.)

Hopefully this helps!